# Strip method does not work on lines from a file

Tags: python, string, strip

I have a csv file transposed and when opened in notepad, it looks like below

```
phone_number,1234,,,
door_number,abcd,,,
name,abcd,efgh,ijkl,mnop
```

below is my code:

```
with open("test.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
       (line.strip(','))
        print(line)
```

However, it does not strip last commas from the csv.

Comment: Likely this is because there is a `\n` to the right of the the `,` and the end of the line. Try `line=line.rstrip().rstrip(',')`

Comment: Also keep in mind that calling `rstrip()` on `line` will have no effect on the contents of the file, even if you assign the result back to `line` as dawg has done. If you need to alter a file, you can't do that just by opening it in read mode.

Comment: Hi Kevin, in this case do I need to write back the contents again back to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this string in Python:

```
>>> line='123,\n'
```

The `\n`  is invisible unless you print a representation of it:

```
>>> print(line)
123,

>>> print(repr(line))
'123,\n'
```

So it is easy to forget it is there.

But `.strip(character)` only works on the last charter. If you do this:

```
>>> line.strip(',')
'123,\n'
```

The comma is not removed. You have to take off the `\n` first, then the `,` and then reassign the new string back to line:

```
>>> line=line.rstrip().rstrip(',')
>>> line
'123'
```

And, as Kevin mentions in comments, that only changes the string -- not the file. To do that, you need to open a different file that can be written to, write your changes, then copy the new file on top of the old file.